# Coil winding direction

Tags: motor, ac, induction-motor

I am having trouble understanding this winding schematic from the book "Induction Machines Handbook" by Boldea, Nasar. This is a winding schematic of a capacitor run single phase induction motor.
[image]

How exactly is the coil wound, and what orientations do the currents take?

Comment: Two phases, 4 pole pairs , right hand rule series or shunt?

Comment: I know nothing about motors, but... This video might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ICsrneFZ12c It's in a foreign language, but starting around 7:30 and through 18:00 the presenter shows the wiring diagram for a single phase 4-pole motor.

Comment: The video assumes an even number of coils or winds (not sure) which is different in my case since I have 5 turns per pole, so the symmetry does not apply.

Comment: @Joeseph123 Are you trying to repair a motor or design one?

Comment: I am trying to design one.